# k3s debuging dns resolution

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, kube-dns

I'm new to kubernetes and I have some issues with my dns names in my k3s cluster on pc with arm architecture.

I've tried to debug as docs (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) suggest

I installed 3ks as follows:

```
sudo curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE=”644” sh -
```

And applied manifest for debugging pod:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml
```

I've checked that pod is running:

```
kubectl get pods dnsutils
```

and tried to run

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
```

and expected smth like that:

```
Server:    10.0.0.10
Address 1: 10.0.0.10

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.0.0.1
```

But get:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

Any thoughts to debug? It seems that I messing smth...

UPD. Tried to debug as rancher suggests (https://docs.ranchermanager.rancher.io/v2.5/troubleshooting/other-troubleshooting-tips/dns):

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=busybox:1.28 -- nslookup kubernetes.default
```

And there is the output:

```
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
Address 1: 10.43.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
pod "busybox" deleted
pod default/busybox terminated (Error)
```

So I tried next step:

```
for p in $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name); do kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $p; done
```

and logs are:

```
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: /etc/coredns/custom/*.server
.:53
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: /etc/coredns/custom/*.server
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = b941b080e5322f6519009bb49349462c7ddb6317425b0f6a83e5451175b720703949e3f3b454a24e77f3ffe57fd5e9c6130e528a5a1dd00d9000e4afd6c1108d
CoreDNS-1.9.1
linux/arm64, go1.17.8, 4b597f8
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:39581->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:52272->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:41480->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:52059->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:46821->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:35222->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:38013->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:42222->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: /etc/coredns/custom/*.server
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:50612->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 4288512074117887106.1437335397389171032. HINFO: read udp 10.42.0.5:50341->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
[WARNING] No files matching import glob pattern: /etc/coredns/custom/*.server
...
```

UPD2

```
kubectl -n kube-system get cm coredns -o yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        hosts /etc/coredns/NodeHosts {
          ttl 60
          reload 15s
          fallthrough
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
    import /etc/coredns/custom/*.server
  NodeHosts: |
    192.168.0.103 ubuntu
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/applied: H4sIAAAAAAAA/4yQwWrzMBCEX0Xs2fEf20nsX9BDybH02lMva2kdq1Z2g6SkBJN3L8IUCiVtbyNGOzvfzoAn90IhOmHQcKmgAIsJQc+wl0CD8wQaSr1t1PzKSilFIUiIix4JfRoXHQjtdZHTuafAlCgq488xUSi9wK2AybEFDXvhwR2e8QQFHCnh50ZkloTJCcf8lP6NTIqUyuCkNJiSp9LJP5czoLjryztTWB0uE2iYmvjFuVSFenJsHx6tFf41gvGY6Y0Eshz/9D2e0OSZfIJVvMZExwzusSf/I9SIcQQNvaG6a+r/XVdV7abBddPtsN9W66Eedi0N7aberM22zaHf6t0tcPsIAAD//8Ix+PfoAQAA
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/id: ""
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/owner-gvk: k3s.cattle.io/v1, Kind=Addon
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/owner-name: coredns
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/owner-namespace: kube-system
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-23T09:06:05Z"
  labels:
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/hash: bce283298811743a0386ab510f2f67ef74240c57
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "315"
  uid: 33a8ccf6-511f-49c4-9752-424859d67d70
```

UPD3

```
kubectl -n kube-system get po -o wide
```

Output:

```
coredns-b96499967-sct84                   1/1     Running     1 (17h ago)   20h   10.42.0.6   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
helm-install-traefik-crd-wrh5b            0/1     Completed   0             20h   10.42.0.3   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
helm-install-traefik-wx7s2                0/1     Completed   1             20h   10.42.0.5   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
local-path-provisioner-7b7dc8d6f5-qxjvs   1/1     Running     1 (17h ago)   20h   10.42.0.3   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
metrics-server-668d979685-ngbmr           1/1     Running     1 (17h ago)   20h   10.42.0.5   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
svclb-traefik-67fcd721-mz6sd              2/2     Running     2 (17h ago)   20h   10.42.0.2   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
traefik-7cd4fcff68-j74gd                  1/1     Running     1 (17h ago)   20h   10.42.0.4   ubuntu   <none>           <none>
```

```
kubectl  -n kube-system get svc
```

Output:

```
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
kube-dns         ClusterIP      10.43.0.10     <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       20h
metrics-server   ClusterIP      10.43.178.64   <none>          443/TCP                      20h
traefik          LoadBalancer   10.43.36.41    192.168.0.103   80:30268/TCP,443:30293/TCP   20h
```

Comment: Are you the only guy who manage this cluster? or you are a team ?

Comment: There is only my

Comment: could you please add also the output of : `kubectl -n kube-system get cm coredns`

Comment: Added as UPD2 ...

Comment: sorry! please add "-o yaml" at the end of the command... and update output: `kubectl -n kube-system get cm coredns -o yaml`

Comment: Updated \(^-^)/

Comment: Ok ! this is identical to mine... Most probably, you have overloap between your host network & cluster network. .. i can conclude your host network from the output.. now let me know your cluster network.. run the following  & put the ouput : `kubectl -n kube-system get po -o wide ` & `kubectl  -n kube-system get svc` .. waiting for you

Comment: Updated one more time)

Comment: @Abdennour take a quick look at updates, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found workaround. When install k3s one should use flag `flannel-backend=ipsec`

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server --write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --flannel-backend=ipsec
```

By default it uses `--flannel-backend=vxlan` I've tried `--flannel-backend=host-gw`
But for me works well `flannel-backend=ipsec`